# Ionic splashscreen hide() method in platform ready doesn't work

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I have problem to hide splashscreen after platform is ready. This is problem only on ios, only on testflight app. I can't build it with cordova 10 locally. When I build locally app with cordova 9 (this is only difference), this method is working.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.splashscreen.hide()
});
```

I'm sure that all imports are ok, all is installed.

package.json: "cordova-ios": "^6.1.0", "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",

config.xml - splashscreen values

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Anyone has idea? I tried add setTimout, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same problem.  In cordova-ios@6.x they [pulled the splashscreen plugin into the platform itself](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/790).  This can also be seen in the [Supported Platforms](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html#supported-platforms) in the latest docs.

What we found was that the call to `.hide()` seems to trigger the hide after `SplashScreenDelay`.  So if you get rid of your `SplashScreenDelay` setting, I bet your calls to `Hide()` will start working as you expect (since you have `AutoHideSplashScreen` set to false already).

If you are like me, and you want the auto-hide ability AND the ability to manually call hide, you can consider just triggering a `.hide()` in a timer, which will fire as a backup plan (in case your other `.hide()` doesn't fire).  It seems there is no negative impacts of calling `.hide()` twice.

```
    //Poor-man's Auto-Hide
    Observable.timer(15000).subscribe(()=>{
        this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
```